# Ошибка: "Cannot read property 'top' of undefined" при создании прокрутки

Tags: javascript

По идее вот так

```
var destination = jQuery("#job").offset().top;
if (jQuery.browser.safari) {
    jQuery('body').animate({ scrollTop: destination }, 1100); //1100 - скорость прокрутки
} else {
    jQuery('html').animate({ scrollTop: destination }, 1100);
}
return false;
```

Должно работать, но ничего не скролится. jQuery подключен. Пишет,

> Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

---

Вопрос из [ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/488307/6) [@Алексей Дементьев](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/198731/).

Comment: У меня та же история . Элемент найден. я его в консоли вижу.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

В данном случае `jQuery("#job").offset()` - возвращает *undefined*, а это возможно только в случае когда `jQuery("#job")` не нашел элементов, удовлетворяющих селектору.

Кроме того в зависимости от версии jQuery при применении этого метода, так же может быть возвращено *null*, следовательно ошибка может меняться на

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of null(…)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вызвать функцию внутри $(document).ready(), может не прогрузился элемент еще

Comment: Это не ответ, а комментарий.